# VLookup then nested If's

Tags: excel, vlookup, nested-if

I have 2 workbooks one named schedule one named AIH. Both of which have agents with unique identifiers.

In the AIH workbook, I have workgroups in which the agents have been trained.They range from Basic,General,Intermediate,Specialty,Non-Dispatch,HP,MB.If the agent has been trained on this, it's marked with an X.

I want to be able to pull the "highest value of training" between these workgroups on the schedule workbook based off the unique identifier that's in both workbooks.

My nested if is as follows:

```
=IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$N$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$N$1,IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$M$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$M$1,IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$L$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$L$1,IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$K$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$K$1,IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$J$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$J$1,IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$I$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$I$1,IF([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$H$2="X", _
    [headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$H$1,"Not Trained")))))))
```

So this rifles through my cells to look for X and displays the highest trained workgroup as i rifle backwards through the columns.

The issue is I need to do a vlookup to match the unique identifier in a column so I can pull the right information based off the agent id(unique identifier) and I'm unsure how to do this as vlookup wants me to return the value of a specific column.

Very new with excel, so the more detailed answer the better for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a quick note the long formula can be reduced to `=INDEX([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$H$1:$N$1,MATCH("Y",[headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!H2:N2))`

Comment: Also what column has the Unique Identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula would be something like this:

```
=INDEX([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!$H$1:$N$1,MATCH("Y",INDEX([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!H:H,MATCH(A2,[headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,0)):INDEX([headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!N:N,MATCH(A2,[headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,0))))
```

Where `A2` is the unique Identifier you want to lookup on the `[headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!` sheet and `[headcount.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A` Is the column on that sheet in which the unique identifier is found.

It can then be copied down the column.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will be trying this the moment I get in.

Comment: This worked perfectly! 

I need to read up on index match a little more, i only vaguely know what's happening here.

Comment: @Benumb please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: can you explain what the MATCH("Y",   portion is doing here? I'd like to replicate this in a professional setting but I don't quite understand that part.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you still need an explanation, but I'll take a crack at it anyway.

If anyone finds an error, let me know and I'll fix it.

Looking at the "outer" `MATCH()`, the one looking for "Y", the definition is...

```
MATCH(value-to-find,range-to-look-in,[match-type])
```

One key is what isn't there--that is, @ScottCraner did not specify the *match-type*, so it defaults to 1, meaning return the largest value less than or equal to "Y" in this case. In the process of looking for the largest value, it continues looking for a "Y" until it runs out of values, which is always the rightmost column that has an "X" in it. It works because "X" is less than "Y", and all your values are "X". Though it also will work looking for "X" instead of "Y". (Not sure why Scott used "Y".)

So that explains what the "outer" `MATCH()` is doing. But where is it looking?

Its *range-to-look* consists of two `INDEX()` functions providing the [upper] left and [lower] right of the range. The first `INDEX()` is returning the cell in column H that is in the row having the identifier (A2) that you're looking for. The second `INDEX()` is returning the cell in column N that is in the same row. You'll notice that the associated "inner" `MATCH()` functions have a 0 for *match-type*, meaning that they find the first exact match.

So, if your identifier (A2) appears in row 20, the *range-to-look* becomes H20:N20, and then the outer `MATCH()` looks for the rightmost "X" in that range, and the outer `INDEX()` returns the corresponding header (top row between H and N).

You must have had to use `IFERROR()` or some other `IF` function to handle the case that there are no "X"s at all, as in the last part of your original formula ("Not trained").